# Compiletime array with constexpr

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, metaprogramming, constexpr

```
    // codenz.cpp
    constexpr uint32_t Hashes[] =
    {
        // ntdll
        crc32::generate("memcpy"),

        // kernel32
        crc32::generate("MessageBoxA")
    };

// hash.hpp
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>

namespace crc32
{
    // Generate CRC lookup table
    template <unsigned c, int k = 8>
    struct f : f<((c & 1) ? 0xedb88320 : 0) ^ (c >> 1), k - 1> {};
    template <unsigned c> struct f<c, 0> { enum { value = c }; };

    #define A(x) B(x) B(x + 128)
    #define B(x) C(x) C(x +  64)
    #define C(x) D(x) D(x +  32)
    #define D(x) E(x) E(x +  16)
    #define E(x) F(x) F(x +   8)
    #define F(x) G(x) G(x +   4)
    #define G(x) H(x) H(x +   2)
    #define H(x) I(x) I(x +   1)
    #define I(x) f<x>::value ,

    constexpr unsigned crc_table[] = { A(0) };

    // Constexpr implementation and helpers
    constexpr uint32_t crc32_impl(const uint8_t* p, size_t len, uint32_t crc) {
        return len ?
            crc32_impl(p + 1, len - 1, (crc >> 8) ^ crc_table[(crc & 0xFF) ^ *p])
            : crc;
    }

    constexpr uint32_t crc32(const uint8_t* data, size_t length) {
        return ~crc32_impl(data, length, ~0);
    }

    constexpr size_t strlen_c(const char* str) {
        return *str ? 1 + strlen_c(str + 1) : 0;
    }

    constexpr uint32_t generate(const char* str) {
        return crc32((uint8_t*)str, strlen_c(str));
    }
}
```

As you can see the function itself and the array is `constexpr` and thus should be evaluated at compile time. The MSVC compiler spits out an error that "expression did not evaluate to a constant". Why is that?

Comment: MSVC's constexpr support has been improving over time. I wouldn't be surprised if the version you use simply doesn't handle this case, but it's hard to say without a [mcve] or the compiler version.

Comment: @chris I have edited the post with a complete example.

Comment: [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/POA80BvJ02uENm0P) and GCC also complain, though the errors are better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove redundant casts:

```
// now we only need one static cast
constexpr uint32_t crc32_impl(const char * p, size_t len, uint32_t crc) {
    return len ?
        crc32_impl(p + 1, len - 1, (crc >> 8) ^ crc_table[(crc & 0xFF) ^ static_cast< unsigned char >(*p)])
        : crc;
}

constexpr uint32_t crc32(const char * data, size_t length)
{
    return ~crc32_impl(data, length, ~0);
}

// we can obtain string literal array size at one go
template<size_t V_array_items_count> constexpr uint32_t
generate(const char ( & str )[V_array_items_count])
{
    return crc32(str, V_array_items_count - 1);
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sU5gUmJ3VO8vRWbP)

Alternatively if you want to keep crc32 interface to accept `uint8_t` or `byte` then you may need to build a corresponding copy array at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Onfortunately this doesn't resolve the core issue / question.

Comment: @Swagov3rflow What do you mean by "doesn't resolve the core issue / question". The issue is that you have those extra casts that can not be used in constant expression.

Comment: The code worked fine before your changes when using it outside of an array (it generated the value at compile time, i checked that). The "core issue" is that it doesn't work inside of an array.

Comment: @Swagov3rflow What do you mean by "it doesn't work inside of an array"? online compiler link demonstrates complete working example that still builds `Hashes` array.

Comment: When running the program locally with your changes (msvc compiler) the Values inside the Array are 0.

Comment: @Swagov3rflow which version of VS are you using? It should work on VS2017

Comment: I was using 2015, After upgrading to 2017 it worked. Thank you!